# calling a cnn_tf module and importing cnn_model_fn in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
import cv2, pickle
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from cnn_tf import cnn_model_fn
```

After executing this code base I am  getting this error :

```
(tensor) E:\codes\Sign-Language-master>python recognize_gesture.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "recognize_gesture.py", line 4, in <module>
    from cnn_tf import cnn_model_fn**
  File "E:\codes\Sign-Language-master\cnn_tf.py", line 5, in <module>
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'logging'
```

my module versions are:

h5py                      2.10.0,
keras                     2.3.1,
keras-applications        1.0.8,
keras-base                2.3.1,
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0,
tensorflow                2.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `cnn_tf` module comes from this [Sign Language Github progect](https://github.com/EvilPort2/Sign-Language), as it seems, notice that in the project requirements it is explicitly mentioned Tensorflow 1.5, and not Tensorflow 2.1. There have been some major changes in the transition from Tensorflow 1.x to 2.x, and the `tf.logging` module is probably not included in v2.1.

You should create a virtual environment and install Tensorflow 1.5 in order to run it successfully; keeping in mind the specific versions of the other requirements is also highly advised.